# SubSonic 2.2 Projections

Tags: subsonic

How do you fashion projections in SubSonic 2.2?   Basically I wish to return columns from two tables that are joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal preference for how to do this is to create a SQL View which joins the table and have subsonic generate an object that maps to it.

You can also use ExecuteTypedList with a custom defined object for example:

```
public class TestObject{
  int Column1 { get; set; }
  int Column2 { get; set; }
}

List<TestObject> testObjects = DB.Select(Table1.Columns.Column1, Table2.Columns.Column2)
  .From(Table1.Schema)
  .InnerJoin(Table2.Schema)
  .ExecuteTypedList<TestObject>();
```